# Calculate value for JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON Object with the below data.

```
{
"1":[{"count":1,"sessionID":"111","timeLogin":2}],
 "2":[{"count":1,"sessionID":"222","timeLogin":3}],
 "3":[{"count":1,"sessionID":"333","timeLogin":3}],
 "4":[{"count":1,"sessionID":"444","timeLogin":3}],
 "5":[{"count":1,"sessionID":"555","timeLogin":3}]
}
```

I want to produce a result - count for each timeLogin.

My expected result should be

```
{"timeLogin":2, "count":1},
{"timeLogin":3, "count":4}
```

May I have any idea from on how or what are the Java technique I can use to calculate the value in order to produce the expected result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for Jackson or some other JSON tooling like GSON, etc.

Basically, you have to first convert your JSON to Java objects. There are multiple ways to do this. You can write your own POJO representation of the JSON, use a generic JSON object like JsonNode or simply use a `Map<String, Object>` to do your work.

You can then just write your logic to add up the total using your object.

Here are some reference links using Jackson:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2 step approach.  First calculate your data, then generate your result object.

If you have multiple objects in your dataset array, you will have to use another loop instead of the hardcoded:

```
  const item = item1[0]
```

```js
const data = {
  "1": [{
    "count": 1,
    "sessionID": "111",
    "timeLogin": 2
  }],
  "2": [{
    "count": 1,
    "sessionID": "222",
    "timeLogin": 3
  }],
  "3": [{
    "count": 1,
    "sessionID": "333",
    "timeLogin": 3
  }],
  "4": [{
    "count": 1,
    "sessionID": "444",
    "timeLogin": 3
  }],
  "5": [{
    "count": 1,
    "sessionID": "555",
    "timeLogin": 3
  }]
}

// First create map of time to count
const counts = {} // time->count
Object.values(data).forEach(item1 => {
  const item = item1[0]
  if (counts[item.timeLogin] === undefined) {
    counts[item.timeLogin] = item.count;
  } else {
    counts[item.timeLogin] += item.count;
  }
});
console.log('counts', counts)

// Next generate an object
const res = {}
for (const key of Object.keys(counts)) {
  res['timeLogin' + key] = counts[key]
}
console.log(res)

// Or generate an array of objects (as you requested)
const res1 = []
for (const key of Object.keys(counts)) {
  res1.push({
    ['timeLogin' + key]: counts[key]
  })
}
console.log(res1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static String calculateTime(JSONObject obj, Connection conn, String db_type) {

     String timeResult = null;
     int nombor_seq = 1;

     ArrayList<String> listTime = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     ArrayList<String> listTimeSort = new ArrayList<String>(); 

     JSONObject JSONmergedTime =new JSONObject();
     JSONObject JSONmergedJSONTime = new JSONObject();

     int objectLength = obj.length();
        for(int uT=1; uT < objectLength+1; uT++) {  //put time, session in one object
            String str = Integer.toString(uT);
            JSONArray arrCreateList=(JSONArray)obj.get(str);
            JSONObject objSession;

            for (Object roTime : arrCreateList) { //roTime

                objSession = (JSONObject) roTime;

                String StimeLoginManipulate =  String.valueOf(objSession.get("timeLogin"));
                int timeLoginManipulate = Integer.parseInt(StimeLoginManipulate);
                String SsessionIDManipulate =  String.valueOf(objSession.get("sessionID"));

                JSONArray jArrayTimeManipulate = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject objManipulate = new JSONObject();

                objManipulate.put("timeLogin", timeLoginManipulate);
                objManipulate.put("sessionID", SsessionIDManipulate);

                jArrayTimeManipulate.put(objManipulate); 
                JSONObject jObjTimeManipulate = new JSONObject();
                String SSEQ = Integer.toString(nombor_seq);
                jObjTimeManipulate.put(SSEQ, jArrayTimeManipulate); 
                nombor_seq = nombor_seq + 1;

                if (JSONmergedTime.isEmpty()) {
                    JSONmergedTime = jObjTimeManipulate;
                    JSONmergedJSONTime = JSONmergedTime; //merged for the first record     
                } else {
                    JSONmergedJSONTime = mergeJSONObjects(JSONmergedJSONTime, jObjTimeManipulate);
                }   
            }//end for roTime     
        } //end for uT

        System.out.println("JSONmergedJSONTime : "+JSONmergedJSONTime);

        for(int uT=1; uT < objectLength+1; uT++) {  //put time, session in one object
            String str = Integer.toString(uT);
            JSONArray arrCalList=(JSONArray)JSONmergedJSONTime.get(str);
            JSONObject objCal;

            for (Object roTime : arrCalList) { //roTime

                objCal = (JSONObject) roTime;

                    String timeInsert = String.valueOf(objCal.get("timeLogin"));

                    listTime.add(timeInsert);

                    if (!listTimeSort.contains(timeInsert)) {
                        listTimeSort.add(timeInsert);
                        Collections.sort(listTimeSort);
                    }       
            }
        }       
        //calculate count - I hard code it since it will be be only 4 result.For non fix value, I perform for loop for timeSort and time list.

        int lengthTime = listTime.size();
        int lengthTimeSort = listTimeSort.size();

        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int count3 = 0;
        int count4 = 0;

        Collections.sort(listTime);

        for (int y = 0; y < lengthTime; y++ ) {

            String listT = listTime.get(y);

            int listIntT = Integer.parseInt(listT);

            if (listIntT == 1) {
                count1 = count1+1;

            }
            if (listIntT == 2) {
                count2 = count2+1;
            }
            if (listIntT == 3) {
                count3 = count3+1;
            }
            if (listIntT == 4) {
                count4 = count4+1;
            }
        }
        //end utk kira

        JSONArray jArrayTime = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jObjTime = new JSONObject();

        //ltk list sort sebagai object
        for (int x = 0; x < lengthTimeSort; x++ ) {
            JSONObject objCalculateTime = new JSONObject();

            String timeSortValue = listTimeSort.get(x);
            int timeLogin = Integer.parseInt(timeSortValue);

            objCalculateTime.put("entry",timeLogin);

            if (timeLogin == 1) {
                objCalculateTime.put("count",count1);
            }

            if (timeLogin == 2) {
                objCalculateTime.put("count",count2);
            }

            if (timeLogin == 3) {
                objCalculateTime.put("count",count3);
            }

            if (timeLogin == 4) {
                objCalculateTime.put("count",count4);
            }

            jArrayTime.put(objCalculateTime);   


        } //end for

        System.out.println("jArrayTime : "+jArrayTime);

        jObjTime.put("1", jArrayTime); 

        System.out.println("jObjTime: "+jObjTime);

     return timeResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 listTimeSort.add(sTime);

 String[] timeArr = new String[listTimeSort.size()];
 timeArr = listTimeSort.toArray(timeArr );

 List aListTime = Arrays.asList(timeArr);
 Set<String> mySetTime = new HashSet<String>(aListTime);
 for(String time1: mySetTime){

     JSONObject objCalculateTime = new JSONObject();
     objCalculateTime.put("entry",time1);
     objCalculateTime.put("count",Collections.frequency(aListTime,time1));

     jArrayTime.put(objCalculateTime);  
 }
```